# View Image in One activity using SqlLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i'm using SqlLite Database to store this image, then retrieve it. 
If i'm click Next button the new image will be display,  but the activity never change. (Sorry my English). image : http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=101dALzioHZuNTHvJ3Vz9UBqk1NrlK0

Comment: What do you want your app to do exactly?

Comment: @MauriF open the image link :)

Comment: Done. What is the 'Next' button supposed to do?

Comment: view the next image. But the activity not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--- EDITED ---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int imgNumber = 1;
...

ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);

...

next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        if (imgNumber==0) {
          imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
          imgNumber++;
        } else if(imgNumber==1) {
          imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
          imgNumber++;
        } else if(imgNumber==2) {
          imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
          imgNumber++;
        } else if(imgNumber==3) {
          imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image4);
          imgNumber++;
        } else if(imgNumber==4) {
          imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image5);
          imgNumber = 0;
        }

        }
});
...
}
```

Comment: i have 5 pictures, i want display a picture in one activity. 
exp: 1st pic is "Earth" . Then, user click button Next 2nd pic displayed "Moon".3rd..4rd.. :(

Comment: how to using 'cursor.getBlob(0)' ?

Comment: Oh the using of  `getBlob` depends on how you stored your image into your data base. Just use the same method you usually use to retrieve the image from de data base, instead.

Comment: can you give me clue to store image into databse?..@Maurif